# Sphinx: Parallel Indexing

Tags: indexing, parallel-processing, sphinx

I use distributed index in sphinx with 5 cores cpu system. So when I want to index/reindex data, I use indexer command like this:

```
indexer idx1 idx2 idx3 idx4 idx5 [--rotate].
```

When command issued, indexer starts to indexing data sequential from idx1 to idx5 and works fine. My question is: How can I do this in parallel to make it faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to spawn multiple indexer processes in parellel explicitly

The `xargs -P` is a useful tool.

Comment: Do you mean: " idx1 idx2 idx3 idx4 idx5 | xargs indexer --rotate ? " Do not need to enter in separate terminals?

Comment: MIssing the a few bits, but fundamentally yes. `echo idx1 idx2 idx3 idx4 idx5 | xargs -n2 -P3 indexer --rotate`   (realised got the capitailation of the -P wrong, sorry!)

Comment: Thank you barry but I have one more question. Why did you use 3 core instead of 5 core? (As I said I have 5 core). 
Is it just for example or is there any special reason?

Comment: just an example really. Although in practice might stillf find 5 processes are too much, in that it overwealms the database for example.

Comment: I tested it with 5 core and I found that time is one-half of the previous time. I expect that I got one-fifth time. Is this because of the same issue you mentioned (overwealming database)? Should I change anything in configuration of database to speed up indexing?

Comment: Would have to diagnose it to find the 'bottleneck' or constraint. It might be the disk - all 5 indexers writing to the same physical disk, indexer does create a bunch of temporally files - so a lot of i/o. If database it might be locks, might be CPU (the database using the same 5 cores), or it again might be I/O related (reading from data from disks, or maybe writing temporally files)